# Prevent Personal.XLSB from opening but keep Macros?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I would like to know if there's a way of preventing PERSONAL.xlsb from opening together with an excel file when Macros are used? Two windows at the same time are a nuisance sometimes.

EDIT: It opens even if I have macros disabled.

Comment: Personal.xlsb should not be visible by default. It may have been made it visible in the past, in which case, [this](https://excelribbon.tips.net) may prove useful reading

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad not visible as in Hidden in the View Options? I have that, but it still opens two excel files, one normal and one empty excel file (the hidden Personal workbook). I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to prevent that blank one from opening in the first place.

Comment: What are those two excel files called?

Comment: One is any excel file that I use, and the second excel file is unnamed. In the second's info it is displayed that it's my Personal.XLSB excel file that I have hidden before. What I'm trying to achieve here is to maybe somehow prevent it from opening in the first place, especially when I don't need its macros at the moment.

Comment: It seems that the Personal.xlsb unhide in this case, you can stay in the Personal.xlsb Workbook and go to View- Select Hide option. The workbook will disappear automatically.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/stop-personal-xlsb-opening-excel/), you can simply click the View tab on the Personal.xlsb window, then click Hide. The personal workbook with your macros still launches in the background when you open a spreadsheet, but it's no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Unhiding, then Hiding, then close/save the Personal.xlsb. https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006205_Opening_Personal_xlsb.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).